# Create final column containing row numbers in text file

Tags: bash, macos, awk, sed, terminal

I am new to using the Mac terminal. I need to add a tab delimited column to a text file with 3 existing columns. The columns look pretty much like this:

```
org1     1-20     1-40
org2     3-35     6-68
org3     16-38    40-16
```

etc.

I need them to look like this:

```
org1     1-20     1-40     1
org2     3-35     6-68     2
org3     16-38    40-16     3
```

etc.

My apologies if this question has been covered. Answers to similar questions are sometimes exceedingly esoteric and are not easily translatable to this specific situation.

Comment: Do you want to put the line numbers in the last column, or something else?

Comment: In the final column, yes. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In awk. `print` the record and the required tab and row count after it:

```
$ awk '{print $0 "\t" NR }' foo
org1     1-20     1-40  1
org2     3-35     6-68  2
org3     16-38    40-16 3
```

Comment: Thank you very much! For future reference, do you know of a way to print a word before each number? e.g. "line_1, line_2, line_3, etc."?

Comment: Just replace the `"\t"` with `"\t line_"` (untested).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add the line numbers to the last column:

```
perl -i -npe 's/$/"\t$."/e' file
```

where

- `-i` replaces the file in-pace (remove, if you want to print the result to the standard output);
- `-n` causes Perl to apply the substitution to each line from the file, just like *sed*;
- `-p` prints the result of expression;
- `-e` accepts Perl expression;
- `s/.../.../e` substitutes the first part to the second (delimited with slash), and the `e` flag causes Perl to evaluate the replacement as Perl expression;
- `$` is the end-of-line anchor;
- `$.` variable keeps the number of the current line

In other words, the command replaces the end of the line (`$`) with a tab followed by the line number `$.`.

Answer (score 0):

You can [paste](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#paste-invocation) the file next to the same file with line numbers prepended ([`nl`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#nl-invocation)), and all the other columns removed ([`cut -f 1`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#cut-invocation)):

```
$ paste infile <(nl infile | cut -f 1)
org1     1-20     1-40       1
org2     3-35     6-68       2
org3     16-38    40-16      3
```

The `<(...)` construct is called [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) and basically allows you to treat the output of a command like a file.